# Paddle hit detection C++

Tags: c++, pong

In the Image the ball will act like it is being hit, anywhere from the top and the bottom of the paddle (anywhere in the range of the white lines). How do I get the ball to only change direction when it hits the paddle?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRYFN.png

```
int Paddle::checkBallCollision(Ball *b){
float paddle_topy, paddle_bottomy;
paddle_topy = this->position.y + length / 2;
paddle_bottomy = this->position.y - length / 2;

int PaddlePX = this->position.x;
int ballPX = b->position.x;
int ballPY = b->position.y;

if ((ballPY < paddle_bottomy) && (ballPY > paddle_topy) && (ballPX - b->width) > (PaddlePX - width / 2  )){
    DebugPrintf(" Paddle Hit ");

    return 1; // there is a collison 
}

else{
    return 0; // there is no collision
}
```

}

Comment: I'd start with Google: [pong calculate angle](https://www.google.com/search?q=pong+calculate+angle).

Comment: `(ballPX - b->width) > (PaddlePX - width / 2  )` -- if your x axis is left-to-right, you want a `<` instead here.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately, now there is no hit detection at all.